# Back navigation with pushstate and load in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using jQuery to dynamically load content into a holder div and then updating the url with pushstate.

I have the following code so far (some excluded for example simplicity):

```
$("body").on("click", "a:not(.noclick)", function(){

    history.pushState({path: $(this).attr("href")}, "", $(this).attr("href"));

    $("#main").load($(this).attr("href"));

    return false
});
```

It works as expected and the url changes to what it should be on new content load but the back button is currently unfunctional, when back is pressed the url changes to the previous but nothing else happens.

I have pages built in a way that you can either use the site with jQuery to load content without headers or without any javascript and pages display from their urls so there's no issue in that part.

Is there a way I could use load on back navigation to load the last pushstate history? I'd prefer to not use hashing but not sure if it's possible without?

Facebook seems to do this with their navigation if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `popstate` event handler.

But why not make this someone else's problem by using [jquery-pjax](http://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

Once you've included the pjax script, probably the following would be sufficient:

```
$(function() {
  $("a:not(.noclick)").pjax("#main", { fragment: "#main" });
});
```

This particular usage doesn't require any server processing to remove the non-`#main` content, but pjax also supports the partial content that you refer to.